# Randomise slave load on Mesos

Tags: jenkins, mesos

trying to solve some problem with Mesos. I have three build servers for Jenkins. Jenkins schedules jobs on them through Mesos. 
For now, Mesos loads one agent(slave) as hard as possible, but I want it to spread jobs across all agents..
As I see, it's better to run three jobs on three agents, than on one.
Is it possible to randomise job scheduling?

Or perhaps, I have such scenario. 2 large servers and one mini. I want to schedule Jobs on mini by default, and if it's not enough resources, then proceed to large servers. How can I achieve this goal? Is it possible to set priority for agents(slaves) to specify on which agent I want job to run at first?

Comment: How do you start Jenkins and its build slaves?

Comment: what do you mean, how? All services in containers. Multiple physical servers for agents, and one VM for Jenkins master. Jenkins slave process launched by Mesos in special container.

Answer (score 0):

The Mesos plugin for Jenkins attempts to build on the most recently built slave (see [this method](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mesos-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/mesos/JenkinsScheduler.java#L380-L396)). This means that once it builds on that machine once, as long as that machine still has available spare resources - it'll schedule additional jobs on that machine until it is full. Right now it looks like that isn't optional (I have filed it as a feature request).